# How to exit from setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need to exit from a running interval if the conditions are correct:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        var properID = CheckReload();
        if (properID > 0) {
            <--- exit from the loop--->
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearInterval):

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  var properID = CheckReload();
  if (properID > 0) {
    clearInterval(refreshId);
  }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: just call `clearInterval(intervalName)`, for example: `var helloEverySecond = setInterval(function() { console.log("hello");}, 1000);` can be stopped by `clearInterval(helloEverySecond);`

Comment: This is a whole new level of ugly from Javascript. Referencing a variable inside its own declaration.

Comment: Why is it ugly @Prime624 ? Doesn't clearInterval clean up properly?

Answer (score 17):

Pass the value of `setInterval` to [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#Clearing_intervals).

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000)
```

---

### Demo

The timer is decremented every second, until reaching 0.

```js
let secondsRemaining = 10

const interval = setInterval(() => {

  // just for presentation
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = secondsRemaining

  // time is up
  if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  secondsRemaining--;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated for ES6

You can scope the variable to avoid polluting the namespace:

```js
const CheckReload = (() => {
  let counter = - 5;
  return () => {
    counter++;
    return counter;
  };
})();

{
const refreshId = setInterval(
  () => {
    const properID = CheckReload();
    console.log(properID);
    if (properID > 0) {
      clearInterval(refreshId);
    }
  },
  100
);
}
```

Comment: What role do braces around refreshId play? Thanks.