# exiting setInterval method in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a setInterval() function which is used as follows

```
        setInterval(function(){

           if(window.document.drops.isFinished()){
               //I want to exit the setInterval() on executing this if
           }

        },1000);
```

or tell me
what is the method to exit.(In java we use System.exit(0))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @juhana is it the same?? i want to exit the setInterval() from inside ,on executing the if condition unless it should continue

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Unless you're talking about exiting the function in that particular case, when you can just use `return`.

Comment: You mean i have to call the clearInterval() from inside the if is it?

Comment: Yes, just like Nico's answer shows.

Comment: It's funny how the duplicates always appear higher in google search than the original questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit from setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795100/how-to-exit-from-setinterval)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
    var timerId = setInterval(function(){

       if(window.document.drops.isFinished()){
           clearInterval(timerId);
       }

    },1000);
```

If the `if` it's not the last thing in the function and you want to "break" the execution, maybe you want to also add a `return;` statement after the `clearInterval`.

Comment: +1. Might be a good idea to add a `return` after the `clearInterval` call too (in case there's other stuff after the `if`).