# How to create a loop and stop it if condition is met?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a function that posts a message to the parent component after 1 second.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
 var widgetHeight =  getDocHeight();
 parent.postMessage(widgetHeight, hostURL);
}, 1000)
```

I want to refactor this so that I create a loop that checks the `widgetHeight` every 1/10th second and if it changed than post the message to the parent and stop the loop.

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you just have to use setInterval instead of setTimeout. setTimeout returns an object you can use to stop the interval to be executed

Comment: You can use `setInterval()` to perform an action at regular intervals.  The return value of `setInterval()` is an identifier for that repeating action, which you can then use to cancel the action at a later time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit from setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795100/how-to-exit-from-setinterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interval to create a repeatable timer.

```
        let timer
        let prevWidgetHeight = getDocHeight(); //Get initial height
        timer = setInterval(function(){ 
          let widgetHeight =  getDocHeight(); //Get the current height
          //Compare new height to previous height:
          if(widgetHeight !== prevWidgetHeight) { //If the current height is not the same as the initial height,
            prevWidgetHeight = widgetHeight 
            parent.postMessage(widgetHeight, hostURL); //Make the update
            clearInterval(timer) //Stop the timer
          }      
        }, 100) //100ms is 1/10th of second
```

This stops the loop once the height differs from the height set before starting the loop. Stopping it means new changes won't be passed on though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't do this in a loop. Since Javascript is single threaded, doing this in a loop would lock the javascript process and effectively block anything from happening except checking for a value that will never change.

As other mentioned, the setInterval method could work... But since you're looking to update something when the document size change. You should instead use this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function (evt) {
    // do something on resize getDocHeight()
    var height = getDocHeight();
    ....

})
```

Note that here, I'm using directly window but it can be any other window object too.

Also more information on the resize event here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize